# Apply contextual class to list item in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider the following HTML snippet using Bootstrap 3:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to apply the contextual classes, info, success, etc, to these **li** elements?

If I try to add, the text color doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a `span` element as stated in the bootstrap documentation.

[**Helper classes**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

> **Dealing with specificity**
>   Sometimes emphasis classes cannot be applied due to the specificity of another selector. In most cases, a sufficient workaround is to wrap your text in a <span> with the class.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./"><span class="text-danger">Default</span> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/"><span class="text-success">Static top</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```